Small/portrait video interface on desktop while remote use is mobile video sdk zoom
Video SDK Version: React Native 1.12.10
Web SDK Version: 1.12.5
Devices:
Mobile: Android Galaxy Tab A8 (React Native SDK)
Desktop: iMac Apple M3, Google Chrome (Web SDK)
Description:
I am trying to join a session using the React Native Mobile SDK with the Desktop Web SDK. The issue is that the Mobile SDK user appears very small on the desktop. However, when a mobile Chrome user joins the desktop session, they display correctly. This issue only occurs with the React Native Mobile SDK user.Mobile sdk user showing portrait
Error:
There is no error, but the following event is triggered on the web:
client.on("video-aspect-ratio-change", async (payload) => { Aspect ratio: 0.5625, Width: 626.625, Height: 1114, userid: 16783360 }
Troubleshooting Steps:
I have searched extensively on the Zoom forum but haven’t found anything directly related to my issue.
How to Reproduce:
Start a session on the desktop using the Web SDK.
Connect using the React Native Mobile SDK.
On desktop Chrome, the mobile user will appear in portrait mode and display at a smaller size.
I have searched extensively on the Zoom forum but haven’t found anything directly related to my issue.
Here is my images of desktop session
https://postimg.cc/gallery/7hMHjZp
